# Elixir Phoenix context authorization (with and without)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I followed the complete tutorial explaining how to handle context & authentication/authorization by @chrismccord ...and I took advantage of his post about decoupling auth from dockyard blog :slight_smile:  [auth for phoenix context](https://dockyard.com/blog/2017/08/01/authorization-for-phoenix-contexts) and from [Adding CMS functions in phoenix context](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/contexts.html)

According to this, In my case( **CMS** is **ENR** ) all created students need an enroller, the enroller is linked to a user(authenticated) with its own session : **Student ->belongs_to Enroller, Enroller ->belongs_to User**, users have their own credentials.

the `resources "/students", StudentController` is protected that's fine.

But Now I want to expose some fact: what about if we want to allow student registering himself/herself? how the code will look like?

for self-enrollment or self-registration instead of doing it by the admin's folk... it'll be good.

here is what I did but I'm always redirect to the authentication page, the result: ***"you have to be logged in"***.

1. when the Admin is logged in/registered.... S/he can achieve administrative tasks (create: Students, Enrollers, pages, etc.) that's allowed by:

   ```elixir
   scope "/enr", HelloWeb.ENR, as: :enr do

     pipe_through [:browser, :authenticate_user]
     resources "/admissions", AdmissionController
   end
   ```

for the admission's tasks

2. In the mentioned case earlier if we consider that scope `CMS` or (`ENR`) is the **admin part** and we want to allow students to register themselves through **public part** I did route like that:

```elixir
    scope "/", InsWeb do
        pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

        get "/", PageController, :index
        resources "/users", UserController
        resources "/sessions", SessionController, only: [:new, :create, :delete],
                                              singleton: true
        resources "/admissions", AdmissionController, only: [:new, :create, :show]
      end

      scope "/ENR", InsWeb.ENR, as: :enr do
        pipe_through [:browser, :authenticate_user]

        resources "/admissions", AdmissionController
      end

      defp authenticate_user(conn, _) do
        case get_session(conn, :user_id) do
          nil ->
            conn
            |> Phoenix.Controller.put_flash(:error, "Login required")
            |> Phoenix.Controller.redirect(to: "/")
            |> halt()
          user_id ->
            assign(conn, :current_user, Ins.Accounts.get_user!(user_id))
        end
      end
```

all seems good I reached the admission page through public part but when I submitted the form ==== nothing..I always got "Login required"
so it's not possible to allow student self-registration...

3. the `AdmissionController.ex` in the **CMS**(ENRin my case) scope looks like:

   ```elixir
     defmodule InsWeb.ENR.AdmissionController do
       use InsWeb, :controller

       plug :require_existing_enroller
       plug :authorize_admission when action in [:edit, :update, :delete]

       alias Ins.ENR
       alias Ins.ENR.Admission

       def index(conn, _params) do
         admissions = ENR.list_admissions()
         render(conn, "index.html", admissions: admissions)
       end

       def new(conn, _params) do
         changeset = ENR.change_admission(%Admission{})
         render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
       end

       def create(conn, %{"admission" => admission_params}) do
         case ENR.create_admission(conn.assigns.current_enroller, admission_params) do
           {:ok, admission} ->
             conn
             |> put_flash(:info, "Admission created successfully.")
             |> redirect(to: enr_admission_path(conn, :show, admission))
           {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
             render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
         end
       end

       def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
         admission = 
           id
           |> ENR.get_admission!()
           |> ENR.inc_admission_views()

         render(conn, "show.html", admission: admission)
       end

       def edit(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
         admission = ENR.get_admission!(id)
         changeset = ENR.change_admission(admission)
         render(conn, "edit.html", admission: admission, changeset: changeset)
       end

       def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "admission" => admission_params}) do
         admission = ENR.get_admission!(id)

         case ENR.update_admission(conn.assigns.admission, admission_params) do
           {:ok, admission} ->
             conn
             |> put_flash(:info, "Admission updated successfully.")
             |> redirect(to: enr_admission_path(conn, :show, admission))
           {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
             render(conn, "edit.html", admission: admission, changeset: changeset)
         end
       end

       def delete(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
         admission = ENR.get_admission!(id)
         {:ok, _admission} = ENR.delete_admission(conn.assigns.admission)

         conn
         |> put_flash(:info, "Admission deleted successfully.")
         |> redirect(to: enr_admission_path(conn, :index))
       end

       defp require_existing_enroller(conn, _) do
         enroller = ENR.ensure_enroller_exists(conn.assigns.current_user)
         assign(conn, :current_enroller, enroller)
       end

       defp authorize_admission(conn, _) do
         admission = ENR.get_admission!(conn.params["id"])

         if conn.assigns.current_enroller.id == admission.enroller_id do
           assign(conn, :admission, admission)
         else
           conn
           |> put_flash(:error, "You can't modify that admission page")
           |> redirect(to: enr_admission_path(conn, :index))
           |> halt()
         end
       end

     end
   ```

And the other one out of **CMS**

```elixir
      defmodule InsWeb.AdmissionController do
        use InsWeb, :controller

        alias Ins.ENR
        alias Ins.ENR.Admission

        def new(conn, _params) do
          changeset = ENR.change_admission(%Admission{})
          render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
        end

        def create(conn, %{"admission" => admission_params}) do
          case ENR.create_admission(conn.assigns.current_enroller, admission_params) do
            {:ok, admission} ->
              conn
              |> put_flash(:info, "Admission created successfully.")
              |> redirect(to: enr_admission_path(conn, :show, admission))
            {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
              render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
          end
        end

        def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
          admission = 
            id
            |> ENR.get_admission!()

          render(conn, "show.html", admission: admission)
        end

      end
```

Any help would be appreciated! thank you!

## Here are the other contents

1. `/templates/enr/admission/form.html.eex`

   ```elixir
   <%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
     <%= if @changeset.action do %>
       <div class="alert alert-danger">
         <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
       </div>
     <% end %>

     <div class="form-group">
       <%= label f, :first_name, class: "control-label" %>
       <%= text_input f, :first_name, class: "form-control" %>
       <%= error_tag f, :first_name %>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
       <%= label f, :last_name, class: "control-label" %>
       <%= text_input f, :last_name, class: "form-control" %>
       <%= error_tag f, :last_name %>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
       <%= label f, :views, class: "control-label" %>
       <%= number_input f, :views, class: "form-control" %>
       <%= error_tag f, :views %>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
       <%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
     </div>
   <% end %>
   ```
2. `/templates/enr/admission/new.html.eex`

   ```elixir
   <h2>New Admission</h2>

   <%= render "form.html", Map.put(assigns, :action, enr_admission_path(@conn, :create)) %>

   <span><%= link "Back", to: enr_admission_path(@conn, :index) %></span>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

With your definition there should be two methods to your `AdmissionController.create` action:

1. `admission_path(conn, :create)` - a POST route to `/admissions`
2. `enr_admission_path(conn, :create)` - a POST route to `/ENR/admissions`

I could imagine, in your new.eex template there's the second one used in the `form_for` method, so every user needs to be logged in.

I would use two controllers instead. If it's not an option for you, you would need a decision, which route should be used. That depends wether there's a user logged in or not.

Comment: thanks for your reply @guitarman, I built 2 controllers but it's the same result. I edited my question to show you the `AdmissionController.ex` in the `CMS` scope.

Comment: I'm using **Phoenix 1.3**.

Comment: I tried the same with a different naming in my Phoenix 1.3 app. The used controller in `resources "/admissions", AdmissionController` is the same for both scopes. Check `mix php.routes`.
Please provide the HTML of new.html.eex and if exists of form.html.eex.